# how to implement multivalued attribute in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I want to store more than one Email IDs in the Email id column of a table, as a multivalued attribute. How can I do this in oracle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The traditional, relational way of doing this would be with a child heap table:

```
create table emails 
    (id number
     , email_address varchar2(254)
     , constraint em_t23_fk foreign key (id)
                  references t23 (id)
                  )
/
```

However, you are hinting at a nested table:

```
create type email_t as object
    (email_address varchar2(254))
/

create type email_nt as table of email_t
/
alter table t23
    add emails email_nt
    nested table emails store as emails_table
/
```

Here's how it works:

```
SQL> update t23
  2  set emails = email_nt (email_t('sam_i_am@example.com')
  3                          , email_t('green_eggs_n_ham@yahoo.co.uk'))
  4  where id = 222
  5  /

1 row updated.

SQL> select * from t23
  2  where id = 222
  3  /

        ID NAME                           DOB
---------- ------------------------------ ---------
EMAILS(EMAIL_ADDRESS)
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       222 Sam-I-Am                       06-AUG-02
EMAIL_NT(EMAIL_T('sam_i_am@example.com'), EMAIL_T('green_eggs_n_ham@yahoo.co.uk'))


SQL>
```

**Edit**

The solution with VARRAY is basically the same:

```
SQL> alter table t23
  2      drop column emails
  3  /

Table altered.

SQL> create type email_va as varray(5) of varchar2(254)
  2  /

Type created.

SQL> alter table t23
  2      add emails email_va
  3  /

Table altered.

SQL> update t23
  2  set emails = email_va ('sam_i_am@example.com'
  3                        , 'green_eggs_n_ham@yahoo.co.uk')
  4  where id = 222
  5  /

1 row updated.

SQL> select t23.name
  2         , e.*
  3  from t23
  4       , table (t23.emails) e
  5  where t23.id = 222
  6  /

NAME                           COLUMN_VALUE
------------------------------ ---------------------------------
Sam-I-Am                       sam_i_am@example.com
Sam-I-Am                       green_eggs_n_ham@yahoo.co.uk

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank u. nw i got.. the concept.

Comment: hey can i use varray to stored multiple record in 1 column ??

Answer (score 2):

The standard way to do this is to define a second table, where you can store one email per row.

Oracle also supports [nested tables](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/NESTED_TABLE) so a single attribute column can contain multiple values.